# Unity: Having the player face the mouse direction. Why does this code work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm on a simple project following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/rQG9aUWarwE?t=382), and one of the first things I need is to have the player point toward the mouse's position.

To do so, I wrote this code by following the tutorial:

```
private void Update()
{
     Vector3 input = Input.mousePosition;
     Vector3 mousePosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(input.x, input.y, camera.transform.position.y));
     transform.LookAt(mousePosition + Vector3.up * transform.position.y);
}
```

Here's the problem: it works, but I don't quite understand *why* it works. I read the documentation on `ScreenToWorldPoint` and am still a little unsure.

My question is twofold:

1. Why do I use `camera.transform.position.y` for the `z` component of the vector that I'm passing in to `ScreenToWorldPoint`?
2. Why does adding `Vector3.up * transform.position.y` work? Without it, if the mouse is too close to the player, it will rotate the body and cause it to move around. With it, the player strictly only rotates in the xz plane.

Edit: Here's a [demonstration](https://www.useloom.com/share/9038a2012a54448bacb37ca7736fb5a8) of the rotation to show that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I use camera.transform.position.y for the z component of the vector that I'm passing in to ScreenToWorldPoint?

The third component of the passed in vector is the z position in world units from the camera. You can read that at the documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

The reason why it's the camera y is because we are looking to get the world point at the ground level, which is camera.y units away from our eye position. If the camera is twice as high, it would still be camera.y units away from the eye position.

> Why does adding Vector3.up * transform.position.y work? Without it, if the mouse is too close to the player, it will rotate the body and cause it to move around. With it, the player strictly only rotates in the xz plane.

I assume that the objects are not at zero y height. So if the world position is at zero y height, it would rotate the body. Therefore the look at point is changed to match the height of the object. When you multiple a vector by a float, the result is a vector where every element is multiplied by the float.

Comment: Ohhh, this makes perfect sense! Especially the reasoning for the second question. Yes, without `Vector3.up * transform.position`, if I move the mouse closer to the player, I see that it starts rotating downward toward the floor. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Note: My answer for 1 only applies to 3D perspective camera usage unlike the OP's situation**

1. The z distance is set to the camera's z position because the depth does not really matter in this case. If you wanted to set the near plane then you would use that as the z distance because that's how far ahead you want to look. It's essentially the distance from the camera to point.
2. Vector3.up = (0, 1, 0), therefore you are omitting the other two axes when adding the transform. I'm pretty sure it's the same as doing `new Vector3(0, transform.position.y, 0)`

Comment: For 1, to clarify, the z distance is being set to the camera's y position, which is what's confusing me.

Comment: `the depth does not really matter in this case` in contrary: you (the ones in the topdown tutorial) want that the position points to something on `y = 0` so they use exactly the position y of the camera as distance value.

Comment: Huh... that's weird. I totally read it as z... using y makes no sense and I don't think you need it to be. Try it as 0 and tell me what happens

Comment: If I change it to 0 and bring the mouse closer to the player, then the player model rotates upward into the sky.

Comment: Wow, that's unexpected. I'm probably missing something here but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I already told you what it is good for guys .. didn't you see my comment above? :D

Comment: Ohhh, it might have helped if I looked at the tutorial XD. I didn't realise it was top down!